# Show answers on review page for questions flagged as "unclear what you're asking"

Tags: feature-request, review, answers, vote-to-close

When reviewing questions which have been flagged/voted as "unclear what you're asking", I need to distinguish between "I don't understand the question" and "no one understands the question".

In this situation, is is helpful to see if others have understood the question. In particular, it is interesting to see what people have answered because if there are real answers, people have at least understood parts of the question.

Strangely enough, the review page doesn't show the answers in this case, requiring me to open the question separately on an additional tab. This should be changed: Similar to questions voted as "duplicates", questions voted as "unclear what you're asking" should be showing the answers, either directly below the question or on an in-page "Answers" tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a question is genuinely unclear, all answers will be *guessing* what the asker intended. If the answerer is confident enough in their answer, that might be convincing enough to look as if the question *wasn't* unclear - despite it being a mere guess.

Showing answers has the potential to lead to yet another quick-and-dirty review behaviour: "It has an answer, so it's not unclear." - regardless of the quality of the answer or question.

It also furthers the argument that "But *somebody* understood it!" is suddenly a reason to keep the question open. It is not. The question *needs* to be clear on its own, because we're helping more people than just the asker - we're also helping the next hundred people with a similar problem. They, too, should be able to understand the question, so they can search for it, and actually figure out that it's *about their problem*.

That said, in order to close a question as unclear, one should at least have reasonably decent experience in the field to determine whether or not it's just a complicated description or indeed lacking information. This does not require any knowledge of the possibly existing answers.